# Load resource file outside jar

Tags: web-applications, jar, classpath, classloader, web-inf

I have created a jar which contains a class that loads an external resource file from class path of my web application. My application is running on resin server. I have deployed my jar in web-inf/lib and my resource file is in web-inf/classes folder. Now the resource file is being accessed using

getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource-name.json");

However, the application throws a null pointer exception when I run it. Could anyone explain to me why my class loader is not able to find this resource file located in web-inf/classes folder? I searched this forum but did not find anything like my problem here.

Like always, I appreciate your responses and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To investigate, first try to print all locations where your `ClassLoader` tries to load classes/resources:

```
((URLClassLoader) getClass().getClassLoader()).getURLs();
```

assuming that the Resign's `ClassLoader` extends `URLClassLoader`. It should contain your folder.

Comment: Thank you Crazhack. Your tip helped. I will mark it as answer since it guided me in resolving this issue, web-inf/classes is indeed in classpath for resin. The error ultimately turned out to be incorrect naming of my resource file.